# join classes in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I am starting to use LINQ and as far as I know in order to use a join query, I need to create manually the return class which will contain the mixed values for the two or more tables I join.

My question is if somebody knows about a tool that helps to create automatically those join classes. To do by hand when the tables are too big is a heavy task, and for maintenance porpouses I think it is very annoying also.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I need to be able to use strong data typed classes and therefore intellisense in VS, I have no problems with the LINQ query itself, only with the join classes to return. I come from the "DataSets world", where my join queries create automatically the corresponding DataTable.

Now I work with ASP.NET MVC, so my method returns a IEnumerable<> type which will be later passed to the View as the model object, example:

```
public IEnumerable<MyJoinClass> GetData(int clientID)
{      
    var query =
    from t1 in objDataContext.table1
    join t2 in objDataContext.table2 on
    new { t1.clientID } equals new { t2.clientID }
    where t1.clientID == clientID
    select new MyJoinClass()
    {   
        //here the fields I want to retrieve... 
        column1_From_Table1 = t1.column1, 
        column2_From_Table1 = t1.column2, 
        //etc...
    };

    //Return result   
    return query;
}

public class MyJoinClass
{        
    public short column1_From_Table1;
    public string column2_From_Table1;
    public short? column3_From_Table1;
    public int column1_From_Table2;
    public short? column2_From_Table2;
    public string column3_From_Table2;
    //lets imagine 50 columns... do I need to do all this stuff on my own?
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to manually create those classes. You can use [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with LINQ, though they aren't as broadly applicable as a coded class. [Here's an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262949/Linq-Join-on-Mutiple-columns-using-Anonymous-type).

Comment: `anonymous type` can't be used if you're going to return result out of function. Another alternative, using of `dynamic` type leave you without support of compiler and IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

With this tool you can actually write the SQL & the tool will convert it into LINQ construct.

Comment: The question appears to be about how to make the type to project into, not how to write the join.

Comment: Ok, I just tested Linquer and yes, it creates the join class with the expected result values, so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool AFAIK, as there is little reason to write one. Do you really ALWAYS want to return ALL the fields from joined tables? Not likely.

What you're probably doing is inner join to filter out the records and adding constraints on linked tables. Getting all the columns from the DB is probably a waste of resources.

You can always create a **view** in DB and query it instead if doing joins manually in code.

Comment: You are right, of course I don't usually fetch all the rows in my join queries, but anyway that could means lot of columns depending on the scenario and as I said if I remove a column or change a column type I need to modify my classes by hand, it is not like the data context file which is auto generated or a DataSet for example, but ok if there is no alternative I will do by hand ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's called "The Compiler". If will let you use an anonymous type, without needing a formal class definition.

Comment: Anonymous types cannot be returned from a function.

Comment: In original question it is author clearly told what exactly he is going to do: _I need to create manually the **return class** which will contain the mixed values_ — anonymous class is not an option here